# How to edit logged in user HTML message?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have Elementor installed on Wordpress and I have used the Elementor Login widget on my site. It basically lets users sign in and after sign in it comes up with a message saying, "You are logged in as...., log out)"... I'm trying to find out how I can edit that LOGGED IN MESSAGE and perhaps add more HTML links under it, I went crazy to find the file that needs to be edited using INSPECT ELEMENT of chrome and no luck finding it. Please let me know if anyone has any ideas.

looked over Chrome inspect element, no luck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvefR.png)

Haven't even been able to locate this elementor login file yet.

Answer (score 2):

The login mmodule php file of Elementor Pro is located in the folder:
[/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/widgets](http://#)

In the *login.php* file, on **line 838**, you will find:

```
echo '<div class="elementor-login elementor-login__logged-in-message">' .
sprintf(
/* translators: 1: User display name, 2: Link open tag, 3: Link closing tag. */
    esc_html__( 'You are Logged in as %1$s (%2$sLogout%3$s)', 'elementor-pro' ),
    wp_kses_post( $current_user->display_name ),
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">', esc_url( wp_logout_url( $logout_redirect ) ) ),
    '</a>'
) .
'</div>';
}
```

And the rest is history :)
Just remember to ALWAYS backup your files before editing them.
Although, if you can not access source files through ftp then your best bet might be to use ACF/frontend to make a login form yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Look in the elementor login plugin files in FTP. Can't find the plugin in the [Wordpress Plugins Directory](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/search/elementor+login/) to have a look for you - is it a paid plugin?

Can you provide a link to the specific plugin. I suspect you will have to edit the code in the actual plugin, which will then likely break as soon as the plugin is updated. There may be an option in their settings, but without having the actual plugin to look at, there's not much I can do!

Comment: the problem is !!!! I can not anything related to the Elementor login widget via FTP !!!!

Comment: Sorry. Start simple here... How did you install it?